# Remove IIS Server Tags through IIS gui only (no code/config)

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, httpresponse, response-headers, iis-10

Have 4 IIS servers... one is on v 6.2, another on v 7.5, another on v 8 and another on v 10.

I've got the following two tags in the response header...

- Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

I managed to remove the  X-Powered-By tag quite easily...via the "HTTP Response Headers" menu on IIS.
However I cant seem to identify a way to remove the "Server" tag via gui.

It is a requirement to do it via the gui of IIS and not programmatically.

- Not via config file
- Not via HttpModule inheritance
- Not via external (1st/3rd) party tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on IIS 10, in IIS Manager, select either the server name or the site name. go to Features pane, under the section Management, select the Configuration Editor. Under "Section" select system.webServer/secruity/requestFiltering under there you'll see "removeServerHeader". Set it to True. If you do it with the server name selected, it will be inherited by all sites on the server.

[image: IIS Configuration Editor Request Filtering]